Precise relation between temperature change and physical quantities
I've learnt that many physical quantities like length or volume etc depend on the change in temperature and some proportionality constant as: $\Delta{L}=l\alpha\Delta{\theta}$. In our physics class, this has given rise to two different equations:
$$
l = l_0(1+\alpha\Delta\theta)
$$where we take $l_0$ at some temperature $\theta_1$, then $\Delta\theta = \theta_2 - \theta_1$, and $l$ is the length at a temperature of $\theta_2$.
But if we assume $\theta_1$ to be $0 ^\circ{C}$ and measure our temperatures from there, we get, in general:
$$l = l_0(1+\alpha\theta)$$
where $\theta$ would be the temperature in degrees Celcius, and $l_0$ is the length at $0$ degrees Celcius. This would then give rise to:
$$
l_1 = l_0(1+\alpha\theta_1)\\
l_2 = l_0(1+\alpha\theta_2)\\
\text{divding,}\\
\frac{l_1}{l_2}=\frac{1+\alpha\theta_1}{1+\alpha\theta_2}
\implies l_2 = l_1\frac{1+\alpha\theta_2}{1+\alpha\theta_1}
$$
The equations above give us two different answers for lengths at a temperature of $\theta_2$ if we're given the length at some given $\theta_1$
I argued, if we take the limiting case, the most accurate formula should be:
$$
dl=l\alpha d\theta \implies \frac{dl}{l}=\alpha{d\theta}\\
\text{integrating,}
\int_{l_1}^{l_2} \frac{dl}{l}= \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\alpha{d\theta}\\
\text{which upon simplification gives us:}\\
l_2=l_1e^{\alpha(\theta_2-\theta_1)}
$$
Which imho should be the most accurate equation out of all the options above, as the rest are just tangential approximations.
The actual question we had is as follows: (It's on resistance actually, but I assumed as the temperature dependence is similar, my argument should still hold.)
The temperature coefficient of the resistance of a wire is $0.00125/^{\circ} C$ at $27^\circ C$. It's resistance is $1\Omega$. The resistance is $2\Omega$ at?
Using the first formula, we get 1100K, the second one gives us 1127K, which are both options in the question. The last equation gives us 854K. What is the correct answer?
Also, if we were only taking approximations, which equation gives a better approximation, the first equation or the second one?

This question is similar to: What is formula for calculating resistance at different temperatures?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe this should be redirected as a duplicate, but a few comments: 1. The temperature coefficient of resistivity (TCR) is temperature dependent and in this context is intended to be applied only at its stated reference temperature. This is 27°C, not 0°C or any other temperature. 2. The linear equation is only an approximation; you've derived a more general equation assuming that the TCR is temperature independent, which it's not.


The original question is poor and misleading because a doubling of the resistance is far too large for the linear approximation to be valid. One could make a case for either 1100 K (linear approximation) or 854 K (exponential expression) being correct; in reality, neither is correct because of the TCR temperature dependence. 4. The use of °C or K in $\theta$ isn't relevant because only temperature differences are being considered; nowhere is a temperature being divided by a temperature.


I get it, thank you!

The same issue arises with the thermal expansion coefficient.

@ekl1pse If you use $\alpha=0.02$, $\theta_{2}=100K$, $\theta {1}=50K$, and $l{0}=1m$, then you have from the first equation, $l_{1}=1(1+0.02(50))=2m$ and $l_{2}=1(1+0.02(100))=3m$. Plugging these into the second equation we get $3=2\frac{1+0.02(100))}{1+0.02(50))}=3$. So the results are the same, not different.

I understand, but this is only if we are given the length $l_0$, which we are not. The way I understood it is that the first equation is a tangent to the real graph at $\theta_1$, the second one is at 0C (and therefore not as accurate), whereas the last one gives us an accurate answer (assuming $\alpha$ remains constant.


$$ \frac{l_1}{l_2}=\frac{1+\alpha\theta_1}{1+\alpha\theta_2} \implies
> l_2 = l_1\frac{1+\alpha\theta_2}{1+\alpha\theta_1} $$ The equations
above give us two different answers for lengths at a temperature of
$\theta_2$ if we're given the length at some given $\theta_1$

You are getting different lengths because you are using degrees Celsius in division. When dividing, you need to use degrees Kelvin.
But the real problem is using the following equation to develop an equation for the ratio of lengths:
$$l = l_0(1+\alpha\theta)$$
The coefficient of expansion is generally given in units of per degree Celsius. But it could just as well be given in degree Kelvin, since $1 K = 1^{0}C$, you should get the same value for $l$ with either unit, but you don't.
Hope this helps.

Should it really matter though? I mean after all I am "actually" taking $\Delta\theta$ with respect to $0^{\circ}C$ right? the temperature difference would remain the same if I take my reference as 273K and measure my difference from there right?

@ekl1pse  Plug in 0 C and 20 C and compare that to 273 K and 293 K. You will get different results even though $\Delta T$ is the same.

Even if I change my units to kelvin, my first equation remains the same: $l = l_0(1+\alpha\Delta\theta)$, but my second equation changes to $l_2 = l_1\frac{1+\alpha(\theta_2-0K)}{1+\alpha(\theta_1-0K)}$. The equations still aren't the same right? $l$ in the first equation is not the same as $l_2$ in the second equation.

What I mean is, assuming $\alpha = 0.02$, $\theta_2 = 100K$, $\theta_1 = 50K$, $l_0 = 1m$, from the first equation we get $l = 1(1+0.0250) = 2m$, whereas the second equation gives us $l_2 = 1 \frac{1+0.02(100)}{1+0.0250} = 1.5m$

@ekl1pse Do you agree you should get the same answer if you use C or K, even if it isn't necessarily the right answer?

in the first formula, for sure as there is no conversion factor between celcius in kelvin. In the second one though you get extra 273s in the denominator if we don't take care of units. But yes, ideally you should be getting the same answer, which is why I think either the first or the last formula is the most accurate

@ekl1pse See update to my answer.

In your answer, you are missing an extra $l_0$ coefficient to the $\alpha\Delta\theta$ term, which poses a problem as we are not given what the length $l_0$ is.

@ekl1pse That's what happen when you skip steps. Will correct. But exactly what formulas are the first and second you refer to?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ekl1pse ok but I won’t be able to get back to you until later
